# Ugly image before Youtube video starts playing in Cordova android app

Tags: cordova, youtube-api

Cordova app, Android device, embedded Youtube video.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ABCD1234?controls=1&autohide=0&playsinline=1&color=white&rel=0&modestbranding=1&fs=0&enablejsapi=1" allowfullscreen="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

When the video has loaded and is ready to be played, an ugly image with a triangular arrow appears when I hit the play button.
[image: ugly background image]

It goes away when the video really starts playing.

How can I get rid of this? On iOS there's just a plain black background, which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <div class="youtube" id="ffiJNSy8CBA" src="https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/paris_france_trees_landscape_62384_1920x1080.jpg" style="width:500px; height:294px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://codegena.com/assets/js/youtube-embed.js"></script>
```

use this [Script](https://codegena.com/assets/js/youtube-embed.js)

[More details & Working Demo](https://codegena.com/change-youtube-thumbnail-in-embed-player/)